# Tomcat war deployed via IntelliJ IDEA 13 is returning error

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm getting the following error deploying my first WAR file in IntelliJ. It is a local issue, supposedly, as this is just a WAR file we deploy to test our setup.

All 80 Maven tests are passing, but when I browse to the web app, I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/ipam] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
    com.myapp1.ipam.rest.JaxRsApplication.<init>(JaxRsApplication.java:26)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1104)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.justCreate(Utilities.java:902)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.create(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:872)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:964)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:956)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.createApplication(ApplicationHandler.java:336)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:285)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:310)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:358)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This seems to be where the problem lies:

```
    public JaxRsApplication() {
    DataSource datasource;
    try {
        Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
        Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
        datasource = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/ipam");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    }
    this.init(new SystemConfiguration(datasource));
}
```

This is my first time using IntelliJ, and I am new to Java, so I'm not sure what to do here.

Here is **context-fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/ipam"
              factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              initialSize="2"
              maxActive="5"
              maxIdle="5"
              minIdle="1"
              maxWait="10000"
              removeAbandoned="true"
              removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
              logAbandoned="true"
              defaultReadOnly="false"
              username="**********"
              password="**********"
              driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
              validationQuery="select 1"
              validationQueryTimeout="5"
              logValidationErrors="true"
              testOnBorrow="true"
              testWhileIdle="true"
              url="jdbc:postgresql://db1host/ipam_dev_table_here"/>
</Context>
```

Comment: You really should check your context.xml file instead.  Are you sure that resource is defined?

Comment: Thanks, I edited my post to show context-fragment.xml. I don't see the issue.

Comment: make sure context-fragment.xml is loaded correctly

Comment: @RichardChen I made a change to this file, so maybe that is it. The filename is blue text, while other files are black text. I'm not sure how to check if it's loaded correctly.

Comment: i am not sure, but you can try the name of Resourse with jdbc_ipam ?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. I just installed IntelliJ for the first time today. I do see this in the manual; file names in blue  mean "File has changed since the last synchronization. " http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/file-status-highlights.html

Comment: I got the repo cleaned and synced with Maven, so the "blue filename" is no longer an issue for context-fragment.xml. This issue seems to be localized, as a co-worker cannot duplicate it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Make sure that you have setup IntelliJ to deploy the context.xml file when it starts tomcat.  You can do this by

1. Select "Project Structure" from the File menu
2. From there, select the "Facets" option.  Make sure that you have a Web facet configured.  If not, add one.
3. Once the web facet is added, select "Add Application Server specific descriptor..."
4. Select Tomcat Context Descriptor from the options and click OK.

By default IntelliJ will point to META-INF/context.xml.  If this is not the location of your context file, you will need to edit the Path to the file.

Comment: Thank you for this post. Spent seven hours trying to find this information.